# Can you set the perforce filetype (especially revisions stored) of a file in the depot without syncing or submitting it?

Tags: perforce

I have a number of files in our depot that have filetype binary. I want to change them to binary+S, so only the latest revision is stored. The only way I can see to do this involves using p4 edit or p4 reopen, which means syncing down the file and checking it out. Then to commit the change, I have to submit the file, too.

This wouldn't be a big deal, but there are hundreds of these files, and they are a gigabyte each, and it's taking perforce forever (hours) to get them submitted.

Is there any way to do this, using the command-line or an API, that doesn't involve syncing down and submitting the unchanged large binary files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `p4 retype` command to change the type of existing revisions.

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 help retype

    retype -- Change rev type or archive (storage) type (unsupported)

    p4 retype [-l -n] -t filetype file[revRange]

        Retype changes the filetype of each revision of the named files
        to the new specified filetype. 'filetype' may be a full or partial
        filetype.  See 'p4 help filetypes'.

        ...

        'p4 retype' does not purge older revisions when a filetype is
        retyped to a '+Sn' type. Subsequent edits cause revisions to be
        purged.

        After changing the type of a file, any client workspaces which
        currently have this file should be refreshed by issuing
        'p4 sync file#none' followed by 'p4 sync file', to ensure that the
        client copy of the file reflects the new filetype.
```

Note the caveats around the +S filetype (old revisions aren't retroactively purged) and needing to do a special re-sync of workspaces that already have the file (you can cheat this with `sync -k` to avoid transferring the file).  If you skip the re-syncing step, a workspace that had the "old" filetype and opens that file for edit will default to the old type (since that type is in the have record for that client file).